# How to enforce already installed gcc-ar to use specific binutils version?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, binutils

I've built GCC 4.9.3 from sources and installed into my home directory with some prefix, e.g. `gcc4.9`.

Now I want to use a newer version of `binutils` along with GCC 4.9.3. I've built them and installed separately in my home directory, with prefix `binutils2.26`.

How I can force `gcc-ar` from `gcc4.9` to use `ar` from `binutils2.26` instead of system one? It always calls `/usr/bin/ar` and looks like there is no options to specify. Replacing `/usr/bin/ar` somehow is not an option - I don't have root access on this machine.

Comment: You should realize that in your build system actually (not letting it call the default gcc-ar).

Comment: How? I call `/home/foo/gcc4.9/gcc-ar` but it still calls `/usr/bin/ar`.

Comment: _"How? I call `/home/foo/gcc4.9/gcc-ar`"_ Call `/home/foo/binutils2.26/ar` instead.

Comment: Will it allow to use `-flto` flag when compiling objects for static libraries?

Comment: Sorry that's beyond my knowledge, I would need to do some deeper research myself about that topic. You may want to clarify your question about that particular requirement. I just wanted to point out that plain calling the specific `ar` version can be easily solved by setting the corresponding toolchain definition variable (`SAR` or whatever) in your build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue.

Using `strace`, I found that `gcc-ar` looks for `ar` in several directories, including `<gcc install dir>/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.3`.

So the obvious solution is to create links in this directory targeting corresponding `binutils2.26` executables:

```bash
  cd "<gcc install dir>/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.3"
  for file in ~/binutils2.26/bin/* ; do ln -s "${file}" ; done
```

After that all, executables in `~/binutils2.26/bin` will be replicated as links in the GCC 4.9.3 directory and will be used automatically when building by that GCC version.

Answer (score 2):

Use GCC's `-B` flag and point it at the directory that contains the `ar` you want to execute. See the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html) for more details on this flag.

```
gcc-ar -B/path/to/your/dir ...
```

It seems to work for me:

```
$ strace -f -eexecve gcc-ar rc foo.a /dev/null |& grep /ar
[pid 14485] execve("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ar", [...]) = 0
$ strace -f -eexecve gcc-ar rc foo.a /dev/null -B/usr/bin |& grep /ar
[pid 14493] execve("/usr/bin/ar", [...]) = 0
$ strace -f -eexecve gcc-ar rc foo.a /dev/null -B/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/binutils-bin/2.26/ |& grep /ar
[pid 14500] execve("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/binutils-bin/2.26/ar", [...]) = 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, `gcc-ar` just passes this flag to `/usr/bin/ar`...

Comment: you saved my day! :)